# MSP430 Program Not Running Outside Debugger

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, texas-instruments, ti-ccstudio

I'm using a MSP430g2231 with EXP430G2 launchpad and CCS.

My code runs fine in the debugger, but when I try to burn it to the MSP and run on external power it doesn't run. It appears that it is not exiting LPM3 with my Timer ISR.

```
#include <msp430.h>

void initTimer_A(void);
void delayS(int secs);

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; //Stop watchdog timer
    P1DIR |= 0x41; //Configure P1.0 and P1.6 as outputs

    BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_1MHZ;
    DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ;

    initTimer_A();
    _enable_interrupt();

    P1OUT = 0x00;
    while(1)
    {
        P1OUT ^= BIT0;
        delayS(7);
        P1OUT ^= BIT6;
        delayS(6);
        P1OUT = 0x00;
        delayS(60);
    }
}

void initTimer_A(void)
{
    TACCR0 = 0; //Initialize timer as stopped
    TACCTL0 |= CCIE; //Enable interrupt for CCR0
    TACTL = TASSEL_1 + MC_1; //Select ACLK, Up Mode
}

void delayS(int secs)
{
    volatile int i;
    for(i=secs; i>0; i--){
        TACCR0 = 4200-1; //~1s delay
        __low_power_mode_3();
    }

    TACCR0 = 0;
}

//Timer ISR
#pragma vector = TIMER0_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A_CCR0_ISR(void)
{
    __low_power_mode_off_on_exit();
}
```

My intention is to make a low power delay that is scalable with at least 1s fidelity. I've already checked the memory on the MSP430 and it appears to be burned correctly. When it runs without the debugger, the red led on the launchpad comes on, but the green one never does. I'm obviously very new to MCs so hopefully it's just a rookie mistake.

UPDATE: I reduced the timer compare value by an order of magnitude and asserted the green led inside the ISR itself, and I began to see it blink. For some reason the clock speed appears to be significantly slower when running outside the debugger. It also seems to be very erratic, with some of the timed interrupts being less than a second, and some being well over 20 seconds. Can anyone explain this behavior?

UPDATE 2: All, I'm happy to say that I have found the source of the issue. I'm posting this update in case anyone has this issue in the future. The root of my problem was that ACLK I was using does not use the internal clock by default. Adding the following line to my initTimer_A function fixed the issue:

```
BCSCTL3 = LFXT1S_2; //Set ACLK to VLOCLK
```

Note: I also discovered that the debugger often ignores the low-power modes and can handle/ignore ISRs, so take that into consideration when writing your code. I was able to verify mine by building in CCS then immediately burning in UniFlash.